# When to use Apples 'SF Rounded' font?

Tags: gui-design, ios, human-interface-guideline, font, typography

Apple uses in certain cases 'SF Rounded' for big titles and number values (e.g. Apple Pay Transaction Detail), in many other cases they still use the regular SF font (e.g. calculator, timer app).

Is someone aware why the rounded font is their choice for currency amounts for big titles? Or is somebody aware of a clear guideline within their HIG?

Answer (score 1):

Apple's guidelines say nothing about the use of SF Rounded. They advise against mixing typefaces, but this may just be considered a variant.

> If possible, use a single typeface. Mixing several different typefaces can make your app seem fragmented and sloppy. Consider using one typeface and just a few font variants and sizes.

From the [Typography page](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/typography/) of Apple's Human Interface Guidelines.

The use of SF rounded may be a style choice for large numbers to appear friendlier or smoother.